# vbs Variable is Undefined: 'objObject'

Tags: arrays, object, vbscript, syntax-error

Ok my problem here is that I'm getting a `Variable is undefined: 'objObject'` error at line 39 char 4. All is good if I remove lines 39-46 but the purpose of the code is to reformat the output from echoing the object which looks like this `z:\\\\BAIBOA\\test.txt` and change it into a string that looks like this `z:\BAIBOA\test.txt` to be used later in the code. This code has been edited from another source so maybe I'm not fully understanding what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Option Explicit
   Dim arrFolders, strComputer, objWMIService, strFolder, strCommand
   Dim i, strQuery, strNewFile, arrNewFile, strFilePath, strTempFilePath
   Dim colMonitoredEvents, strQueryFolder


   arrFolders = Array("Z:\\\\test1", "Z:\\\\test2", "Z:\\\\test2")

   strComputer = "."
   'strQueryFolder = Replace(strFolder, "\", "\\\\")
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer _
                           & "\root\CIMV2")
   'Loop through the array of folders setting up the monitor for Each
i = 0
  For Each strFolder In arrFolders
  'Create the event sink
  strCommand = "Set EventSink" & i & " = WScript.CreateObject" & _
               "(""WbemScripting.SWbemSink"", ""SINK" & i & "_"")"
  ExecuteGlobal strCommand
  'Setup Notification
  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 " & _
             "WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile'" & _
             " and TargetInstance.GroupComponent = " & _
             "'Win32_Directory.Name=""" & strFolder & """'"

  strCommand = "objWMIservice.ExecNotificationQueryAsync EventSink" & _
               i & ", strQuery"
  ExecuteGlobal strCommand
  'Create the OnObjectReady Sub
  strCommand = "Sub SINK" & i & "_OnObjectReady(objObject, " & _
               "objAsyncContext)" & VbCrLf & vbTab & _
               "Wscript.Echo objObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent" & _
               VbCrLf & "End Sub"

  'WScript.Echo strCommand

  ExecuteGlobal strCommand
  i = i + 1

---> Line 39    Set objLatestEvent = objObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
 strNewFile = objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
 arrNewFile = Split(strNewFile, "=")
 strFilePath = arrNewFile(1)
 strFilePath = Replace(strFilePath, "\\", "\")
 strFilePath = Replace(strFilePath, Chr(34), "")
 strFileName = Replace(strFilePath, strFolder, "")
 'strTempFilePath = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\TEMP.M4A"

 Wscript.Echo strFilePath

 Next
   WScript.Echo "Waiting for events..."

   i = 0
   While (True)
       Wscript.Sleep(1000)
   Wend
```

Ok Ive came up with a solution for the output but now im stuck getting the script to increment correctly and will only goto the next folder if the first folder gets a file. What i need is for it to scan the array for new files not 1 by 1. :( any suggestions

```
 Option Explicit
   Dim arrFolders, strComputer, objWMIService, strFolder, strCommand
   Dim i, strQuery, strNewFile, arrNewFile, strFilePath, strTempFilePath
   Dim colMonitoredEvents, strQueryFolder, objObject, objLatestEvent
   Dim strFileName

   arrFolders = Array("Z:\\\\test1", "Z:\\\\test2", "Z:\\\\test2")

 strComputer = "."
   i = 0
   For Each strFolder In arrFolders

 'trQueryFolder = Replace(strFolder, "\", "\\\\")

 strQueryFolder = strFolder

 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
 Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 " & " WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent='Win32_Directory.Name=""" & strQueryFolder & """'") 

 Wscript.Echo strQueryFolder

 'Do 
     Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent

     strNewFile = objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
     arrNewFile = Split(strNewFile, "=")
     strFilePath = arrNewFile(1)
     strFilePath = Replace(strFilePath, "\\", "\")
     strFilePath = Replace(strFilePath, Chr(34), "")
     strFileName = Replace(strFilePath, strFolder, "")
     strTempFilePath = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\TEMP.M4A"

     ' DO THE OPERATION STUFF
     ' ...
       'Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
       Wscript.Echo strFilePath
 '    If strFileName = strQueryFolder then i = i + 1 Else

 'Loop

       i = i + 1
   Next
   'WScript.Echo "Waiting for events..."

   i = 0
   While (True)
       Wscript.Sleep(1000)
  Wend
```

Comment: With `Option Explicit` you need to add `objObject` to the Dim list.

Comment: @QuickNull you might as well answer and get the points. :D

Comment: Sorry must have missed that one in the Dim. Unfortunately it still resulted in the same error. I was hoping this new approach would correct my previous issue but then resulted in a new issue as stated above.

Comment: I don't see where objObject is ever assigned anything.  You're trying to pull data from objObject (in this case objObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent) but objObject is empty.

Comment: Your correct and i believe that my second edition below corrects the objObject. Only now it doesn't increment properly. :/